# Plus construction on Simplicial Sets?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, algebraic-k-theory

Write $\mathsf{sSet}$ for the category of simplicial sets and $\mathsf{Top}$ for the category of topological spaces. I would like to know if there a functor $\mathsf{sSet}\to\mathsf{sSet}$ that resembles the plus construction in $\mathsf{Top}$?

More precisely, let $G$ be a (perfect) group and $|BG|$ the classifying space of $G$, by the geometric realization of the nerve construction (so $BG$ is the simplicial set with $B_{n}G$ = set of all tuples $(g_1, \cdots ,g_n)$, with the natural face and degeneracy maps. And, $|BG| = $ geometric realization of the simplicial set $BG$. I'm using the construction given in Weibel's "An introduction to Homological Algebra" book, Page 257).

The question is as follows :

Does there exist a functor (denoted with slight abuse of notation) $(-)^{+}\colon\mathsf{sSet}\to\mathsf{sSet}$, such that
$|(BG)^{+}| \cong (|BG|)^{+}$  for any group $G$?

In other words, can we make a plus construction in simplicial sets, so that it commutes with the geometric realization functor?

Comment: Do you really want an isomorphism $BG^+\cong|(B_\bullet G)^+|$, or is a canonical (weak) homotopy equivalence $BG^+\simeq|(B_\bullet G)^+|$ also good enough? (I personally prefer to not even have $BG$ be defined up to isomorphism, but only up to weak equivalence, so if you want it to hold up to isomorphism, please let us know how exactly you define the topological space $BG$.)

Comment: I would prefer homeomorphism but canonical (weak) homotopy equivalence should be good enough as well.
As for the definition of $BG$ - I made a mistake so I've edited my post. Thanks! :)

Comment: Moreover, I'm interested in the case when $G$ is a perfect group (hence the plus construction $(|BG|)^{+}$ is simpler in this case).

Comment: In the case of Kan complexes with perfect fundamental group, there is definitely a simplicial analogue, basically by mimicking the topological construction (but e.g. using the simplicial description for homotopy groups of Kan complexes). I just don't see how to 1) extend it to all Kan complexes, because I don't know if the covering space techniques can be performed purely inside simplicial sets, and 2) extend it to all simplicial sets, because for non-Kan complexes we usually lack the ability to perform analogues of topological constructions.